# SNPE inference outputs misaligned images

Tags: java, android, pytorch, onnx, snpe

I am working on a de-weatherization android app adopting a pix2pix model (similar to UNET). the app mainly uses the phone camera (one plus 7) to capture images, de-weatherize and display the result in the main interface. The deep learning inference interface adopts Qualcomm's SNPE framework.
Currently, we encountered a problem that the **output of the model to Bitmap is misaligned**, as shown in the figure.
[image: misaligned pic]
Here's the inference code：

```
    final List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

    final FloatTensor tensor = mNeuralNetwork.createFloatTensor(
            mNeuralNetwork.getInputTensorsShapes().get(mInputLayer));

    Log.e("[MODEL]", "create tensor");
    Bitmap smImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mImage, 1080, 720, true);

    final int[] dimensions = tensor.getShape();
    final boolean isGrayScale = (dimensions[dimensions.length -1] == 1);
    float[] rgbBitmapAsFloat;
    if (!isGrayScale) {
        rgbBitmapAsFloat = loadRgbBitmapAsFloat(smImage);
    } else {
        rgbBitmapAsFloat = loadGrayScaleBitmapAsFloat(smImage);
    }
    tensor.write(rgbBitmapAsFloat, 0, rgbBitmapAsFloat.length);

    Log.e("[MODEL]", "create tensor done!");
    final Map<String, FloatTensor> inputs = new HashMap<>();
    inputs.put(mInputLayer, tensor);
    Log.e("[MODEL]", "create input tensor done!");

    final long javaExecuteStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    final Map<String, FloatTensor> outputs = mNeuralNetwork.execute(inputs);
    Log.e("[MODEL]", "model execute!");
    final long javaExecuteEnd = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    mJavaExecuteTime = javaExecuteEnd - javaExecuteStart;
    FloatTensor outputTensor = new FloatTensor() {
        @Override
        public void write(float[] floats, int i, int i1, int... ints) {

        }

        @Override
        public void write(float v, int... ints) {

        }

        @Override
        public int read(float[] floats, int i, int i1, int... ints) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float read(int... ints) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void release() {

        }
    };
    for (Map.Entry<String, FloatTensor> output : outputs.entrySet()) {
        Log.e("[MODEL]", "output_layer: " + output.getKey());
        if (output.getKey().equals(mOutputLayer)) {
            outputTensor = output.getValue();
            Log.e("[MODEL]", "output_layer: " + output.getKey() + ", shape: " +
                    String.valueOf(outputTensor.getShape()[0]) + " " +
                    String.valueOf(outputTensor.getShape()[1]) + " " +
                    String.valueOf(outputTensor.getShape()[2]) + " " +
                    String.valueOf(outputTensor.getShape()[3]) + " " );
            }
        }
    return outputTensor;`
```

And, here's the code that convert SNPE Floattensor to JAVA Bitmap:

```
final float[] pixelsBatched = new float[tensor.getSize()];
    tensor.read(pixelsBatched, 0, tensor.getSize());
    Log.i("[IMAGE]", "size: " + String.valueOf(tensor.getSize()));
    int w = 1080;
    int h = 720;
    Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            float r = pixelsBatched[y * w * 3 + x * 3 + 0] * 255;
            float g = pixelsBatched[y * w * 3 + x * 3 + 1] * 255;
            float b = pixelsBatched[y * w * 3 + x * 3 + 2] * 255;
            int color = ((int)r << 16) | ((int)g << 8) | (int)b | 0xFF000000;
            img.setPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }

    return img;
```

To further analyze this issue, I took the input tensor and **output it directly** instead of inferring it.

`return tensor;`

After converting the input tensor to Bitmap, **I found that the image is correct**. Therefore, **I'm guessing if the inference step is wrong**.
I used the Pytorch framework for training and the trained model was exported to the ONNX. I tested the model in pytorch framework and the model outputs the correct image. Then, model was then simplified by onnx-sim and converted to a dlc model by SNPE's conversion tool. The struct of onnx network is shown below.
[image]
I would like to ask what are the possible reasons for the occurrence of this misalignment. Thank you very much!

####################
Update!##################

```
    int channelSize = w * h;
    float r = pixelsBatched[y * w + x] * 255;
    float g = pixelsBatched[y * w + x + channelSize] * 255;
    float b = pixelsBatched[y * w + x + 2 * channelSize] * 255;
```

Here's the result:
[image]

############################ Update! ##############################

The result of snpe-dlv-viewer:
[image]

The information of input layer:
[image]

The information of output layer:
[image]

############################ Update! ##########################

```
float[] loadRgbBitmapAsFloat(Bitmap image) {
    final int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
    image.getPixels(pixels, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0,
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    final float[] pixelsBatched = new float[pixels.length * 3];
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            final int idx = y * image.getWidth() + x;
            final int batchIdx = idx * 3;

            final float[] rgb = extractColorChannels(pixels[idx]);
            pixelsBatched[batchIdx]     = rgb[0];
            pixelsBatched[batchIdx + 1] = rgb[1];
            pixelsBatched[batchIdx + 2] = rgb[2];
        }
    }
    return pixelsBatched;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have gotten the layout of the output tensor wrong.
When you iterate over the output tensor like this:

```
float r = pixelsBatched[y * w * 3 + x * 3 + 0] * 255;
float g = pixelsBatched[y * w * 3 + x * 3 + 1] * 255;
float b = pixelsBatched[y * w * 3 + x * 3 + 2] * 255;
```

You read the `R`, `G`, and `B` values sequentially. However, the output tensor layout is `1x3x1080x720`, meaning all `R` values are stored sequentially, then all `B` values, then all `G` values.

So, you need to define

```
int channelSize = w * h;
```

then, you read them like this:

```
float r = pixelsBatched[y * w + x] * 255;
float g = pixelsBatched[y * w + x + channelSize] * 255;
float b = pixelsBatched[y * w + x + 2 * channelSize] * 255;
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that the shape of onnx is nchw (channel first). However, when the model is converted to snpe's dlc, the shape changes to nhwc (channel last). Still, I tried to modify the code as you described (please see modifications) and it looks like the result is even more incorrect.

Comment: Ok, so probably snpe changes the layout again. Can you share visualize the model stored in dlc using snpe-dlc-viewer and share the result?

Comment: OK! Please check the last update.

Comment: Great, so note that the output tensor in the DLC has the shape 1x1080x720x3, so your original code for reading the output is correct. However, the input tensor's layout does not match the layout in the ONNX model. Can you share the code for `loadRgbBitmapAsFloat()` function?

Comment: Sure! Please check out the latest updates.

Comment: Ok, I've read your code again and I can't see anything that's stands out as wrong. However, I don't quite understand your original screenshot. Your input and output images have a shape of 1080x720 (width times height), but your screen is in portrait mode and it's height is larger than it's width. How does your output Bitmap object map to the screen output? Perhaps there's some scaling issue going on?